# Block a partcular machine for a particular period of time interval

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, atomic, google-guava-cache

I am working on a library where I make Http call to my service and if my service machine doesn't respond back (there is a socket timeout or connect timeout), I add them to my local `blockList` and if machine is blocked 5 times then I don't make call to them.

So let's say if  `machineA` is not responding `(throwing RestClientException)`, I will call `onFailure` method everytime and keep incrementing the counter and then while making call to `machineA` again, I check `isBlocked` method by passing `machineA` as hostname and 5 as threshold so if `machineA` has been blocked 5 times then I don't make call to them at all. My library is multithreaded so that's why I am using volatile here as I want all threads to see same value.

Below is what I have in `DataMapping` class:

```
public static volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> blockedHosts =
      new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

boolean isBlocked(String hostname, int threshold) {
    AtomicInteger count = blockedHosts.get(hostname);
    return count != null && count.get() >= threshold;
}

void onFailure(String hostname) {
    AtomicInteger newValue = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger val = blockedHosts.putIfAbsent(hostname, newValue);
    // no need to care about over-reaching 5 here
    (val == null ? newValue : val).incrementAndGet();
}

void onSuccess(String hostname) {
    blockedHosts.remove(hostname);
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I want to add one more feature which is - If `machineA` is blocked (since its blocking count is >= 5) then I want to keep it block for x interval. I will be having another parameter `(key.getInterval())` which will tell us for how long I want to keep this machine blocked and after that interval is elapsed, then only I will start making call to them. I am not able to understand how to add this feature?

Below is my main thread code where I am using `DataMapping` methods to check whether hostname is blocked or not and also to block hostnames.

```
@Override
public DataResponse call() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

    List<String> hostnames = some_code_here;

    for (String hostname : hostnames) {
        // If hostname is in block list, skip sending request to this host
        if (DataMapping.isBlocked(hostname)) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            String url = createURL(hostname);
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(), String.class);
            DataMapping.onSuccess(hostname);

            // some code here to return the response if successful
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            // adding to block list
            DataMapping.onFailure(hostname);
        }
    }

    return new DataResponse(DataErrorEnum.SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);        
}
```

How can I block a particular machine for a particular period of time and as soon as that interval is elapsed then only start making calls to them?

Comment: You need to keep track of when it became blocked in order to tell if the interval has elapsed, not just whether it is blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and `schedule` the reset of the counter after a certain timeout.

You can declare this within your `DataMapping` class:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); // or perhaps the thread pool version ?
```

And within your `onFailure()` method you can decide whether you want to *reset* or just *decrement* the counter after a certain timeout:

```
void onFailure(String hostname) {
    // you can use `computeIfAbsent` in java8
    AtomicInteger val = blockedHosts.computeIfAbsent(hostname, key -> new AtomicInteger());
    int count = val.incrementAndGet();
    // the test here is `==` to make sure the task is scheduled only once
    if (count == threshold) {
        scheduler.schedule(() -> blockedHosts.remove(hostname), 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);  // or you may choose to just decrement the counter
    }
}
```

As a side note, there's no reason to make `blockedHosts` `volatile`. That reference never changes; it should be `final` instead; and probably `private`.

---

In java7, the above code would look like this:

```
void onFailure(String hostname) {
    AtomicInteger newValue = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger val = blockedHosts.putIfAbsent(hostname, newValue);
    int count = (val == null ? newValue : val).incrementAndGet();
    // the test here is `==` to make sure the task is scheduled only once
    if (count == threshold) {
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                blockedHosts.remove(hostname);  // or you may choose to just decrement the counter
            }
        }, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Java 7 yet and I cannot move to Java 8. How will this look like with Java 7?

Comment: Pretty much the same, except for `computeIfAbsent` and the neat lambda syntax. You'll have to instantiate a `Callable` (or `Runnable`) and submit it to the executor service.

Comment: Can you update this with Java 7 suggestion as well. I am still trying to understand what does above code do. I will have few questions once I see in Java 7 just to make sure I understand.

Comment: Done. I hope it compiles :)

Comment: Yeah I think it will compile for sure. We have hardcoded the `5` minute window so instead of that if I pass in the method, then that should also work right?

Comment: That was just an example, you can compute the timeout in any way you see fit. I'm not sure I understand what "pass in the method" means though...

Comment: Also this if check we have here `if (count == threshold) {`. Does this should be `>=` instead of `==` since we have multiple threads here?

Comment: You can use `>=`, but you'll need to make sure that you don't schedule the same counter removal multiple times. With `==`, that will only happen once so you don't need to worry. You can count on one (and only one) thread getting that exact value eventually -- unless that `AtomicInteger` is changed from outside this class.

Comment: I have a new question which is exactly based on this question, only difference is there is a slight change in the requirement. I have got it working, wanted to make sure what I am doing is right or not. Here is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925494/how-to-keep-retrying-block-machine-every-x-interval-until-url-is-executed-succes).